# Remove left margin from materialdrawer

Tags: android, material-design, drawer, materialdrawer

How to remove the space Mikepenz Material Drawer.I used custom layout for profile menu and drawer Items. I didnt set Margin or padding for those views. And i also tried activity horizontal margin to 0.[image]
Help would be appreciated. same margin right side also. Profile menu is Ok. it has no problem.whereas draweritem facing the problem.

Below code is Profile Menu

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUserProfileImage"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/min_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/parent" />

            <com.CustomTextView

                android:id="@+id/txtUserName"

                style="@style/label_text_primary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Noorul"
                app:font="@string/montserrat_semi_bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/min_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/min_margin"
            android:background="#999999" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And Below Code is for Drawer Item Menu

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lnrSecond_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/material_drawer_item_secondary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/material_drawer_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_img"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_img"
            android:padding="@dimen/most_most_normal_margin"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/material_drawer_name"
            style="@style/label_text_secondary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:text="Some Secondary Text"
            app:font="@string/montserrat_regular"
            />

        <com.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/material_drawer_description"
            style="@style/label_text_secondary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:font="@string/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="Some drawer text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/material_drawer_badge_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right|center">

        <com.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMenuBadge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/min_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="99" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where I made the Mistake? Help me i will be grateful to you guys.

Comment: Please add comment when you people downvoted the question. Because, I am unaware of android deeply. I want to correct my self . whether this question is wrong or not. Thankyou.

Comment: Probably downvoted because you had no code initially. You could try negative margins if there is 0 margin currently

Comment: yes i tried the same thing you said. but the indicator hides when i try to set  negative margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drawer adds this `padding` because it is default for all items inside the `Material Design Guidelines`. As there is an issue with API 17 I have to set this programatically in this line:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/model/BasePrimaryDrawerItem.java#L104

You might also want to post the `DrawerItem`s you use, as the screenshot does not look like you use the default items.

If you already create your own `CustomDrawerItem` you just want to set the padding to 0px again (If you extend from the `BasePrimaryDrawerItem`) If you do not extend from it you should be fine.

The drawer does not set this padding on the items anywhere else than here.